# Performance impact on Lean jar vs Heavy jar loading in a Web application

Tags: java, jar

Suppose, you have a JAR which is 14MB large & a JAR which is stripped of unwanted classes to a size of 6.5MB.

When deployed to Web application's WEB-INF/lib folder, will there be any impact on the performance between deploying a heavy jar vs the lean jar? If yes, What improvements can I expect?

Answer (score 0):

Except for disk access when exploding the war file, you should see identical behavior due to the way class loaders work.

It is, however, dependent on the underlying platform.  I would suggest you do some testing to convince yourself of the actual numbers.